# SAPUI5 aggregation of tables doesn't work

Tags: json, aggregate, sapui5, graphviz

I'm new to SAPUI5 and I'm trying to aggregate some JSON data before displaying in a column chart.

Here are some lines of my code:

```
var xsodataURL = 'That is my URL to my xsodata';
var oModelBU = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(xsodataURL, false);
oModelBU.bindList('/PM_PROJECT', false, {
    select: 'PMBudget, PMActual, PMEAC'
});

var oDatasetBU = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({
    dimensions: [{
        axis: 1,
        name: 'ProgramID: Overall Result',
        value: ''
    }],

    measures: [
        [{
            name: 'Budget',
            value: '{PMBudget}'
        }, {
            name: 'Actual',
            value: '{PMActual}'
        }, {
            name: 'EAC',
            value: '{PMEAC}'
        }]
    ],

    data: {
        path: '/PM_PROJECT'
    }
});

var oChartBU = new sap.viz.ui5.Column({
    width: '100%',
    height: calcChartHeight,
    legendGroup: {
        layout: {
            position: 'bottom'
        }
    },
    plotArea: {
        colorPalette : d3.scale.category20().range()
    },
    title: {
        visible: true,
        text: 'Budget use in mEUR',
        alignment: 'left'
    },
    dataset: oDatasetBU
});
oChartBU.setModel(oModelBU);
```

Actually everything works fine, but the application just display the JSON data of the last item in my xsodata. That's why I tried to aggregate the data in the xsodata file like:

```
"PM_SHOWCASE"."PM_PROJECT" aggregates always(SUM of "PMBudget", SUM of "PMActual", SUM of "PMEAC");
```

But that doesnt work - does anyone know, how I can display ALL data aggregated as SUM of the table "PM_PROJECTS"? Thanks in advance!

Have a great day, Arne.